# In Jupyter notebook the Julia 1.8.2 Kernel fails to start

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, julia

I installed Julia as a separate environment in Ananconda. When I run the Jupyter notebook from the base (default) environment and attempt to create a new kernel using Julia 1.8.2, the kernel never starts. It restarts and fails repeatedly.
I have tried multiple times to install "IJulia" package through the julia REPL/console, but each time it shows a "Precompile error" with one dependencies from that package and it is "IJulia".

The following is the terminal output when trying to create and run a new notebook with julia 1.8.2 kernel in Jupyter notebook:

```
(base) user@Ideapad-320-14IKB:~$ jupyter notebook
[I 2022-10-22 22:38:19.300 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jupyterlab
[I 2022-10-22 22:38:19.300 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is /home/user/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab
[I 22:38:19.304 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/user
[I 22:38:19.304 NotebookApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.4.12 is running at:
[I 22:38:19.304 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=e67639f228570093a6050632d9de6e98870f034e2923bfb5
[I 22:38:19.304 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=e67639f228570093a6050632d9de6e98870f034e2923bfb5
[I 22:38:19.304 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 22:38:19.355 NotebookApp] 
    
    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///home/user/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-27914-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=e67639f228570093a6050632d9de6e98870f034e2923bfb5
     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=e67639f228570093a6050632d9de6e98870f034e2923bfb5
[I 22:38:57.111 NotebookApp] New terminal with automatic name: 1
TermSocket.open: 1
TermSocket.open: Opened 1
[I 22:40:23.823 NotebookApp] Creating new notebook in 
[I 22:40:25.845 NotebookApp] Kernel started: c0c716fc-b629-46d7-aa29-44e1cb91c0fc, name: julia-1.8
ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: Package IJulia not found in current path.
- Run `import Pkg; Pkg.add("IJulia")` to install the IJulia package.
Stacktrace:
 [1] macro expansion
   @ ./loading.jl:1163 [inlined]
 [2] macro expansion
   @ ./lock.jl:223 [inlined]
 [3] require(into::Module, mod::Symbol)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:1144
in expression starting at /home/user/anaconda3/envs/julialang/share/julia/packages/IJulia/AQu2H/src/kernel.jl:1
[I 22:40:28.835 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), new random ports
ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: Package IJulia not found in current path.
- Run `import Pkg; Pkg.add("IJulia")` to install the IJulia package.
Stacktrace:
 [1] macro expansion
   @ ./loading.jl:1163 [inlined]
 [2] macro expansion
   @ ./lock.jl:223 [inlined]
 [3] require(into::Module, mod::Symbol)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:1144
in expression starting at /home/user/anaconda3/envs/julialang/share/julia/packages/IJulia/AQu2H/src/kernel.jl:1
[I 22:40:31.874 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (2/5), new random ports
ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: Package IJulia not found in current path.
- Run `import Pkg; Pkg.add("IJulia")` to install the IJulia package.
Stacktrace:
 [1] macro expansion
   @ ./loading.jl:1163 [inlined]
 [2] macro expansion
   @ ./lock.jl:223 [inlined]
 [3] require(into::Module, mod::Symbol)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:1144
in expression starting at /home/user/anaconda3/envs/julialang/share/julia/packages/IJulia/AQu2H/src/kernel.jl:1
[I 22:40:34.909 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (3/5), new random ports
ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: Package IJulia not found in current path.
- Run `import Pkg; Pkg.add("IJulia")` to install the IJulia package.
Stacktrace:
 [1] macro expansion
   @ ./loading.jl:1163 [inlined]
 [2] macro expansion
   @ ./lock.jl:223 [inlined]
 [3] require(into::Module, mod::Symbol)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:1144
in expression starting at /home/user/anaconda3/envs/julialang/share/julia/packages/IJulia/AQu2H/src/kernel.jl:1
[I 22:40:37.945 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (4/5), new random ports
ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: Package IJulia not found in current path.
- Run `import Pkg; Pkg.add("IJulia")` to install the IJulia package.
Stacktrace:
 [1] macro expansion
   @ ./loading.jl:1163 [inlined]
 [2] macro expansion
   @ ./lock.jl:223 [inlined]
 [3] require(into::Module, mod::Symbol)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:1144
in expression starting at /home/user/anaconda3/envs/julialang/share/julia/packages/IJulia/AQu2H/src/kernel.jl:1
[I 22:40:40.983 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (5/5), new random ports
Websocket closed
ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: Package IJulia not found in current path.
- Run `import Pkg; Pkg.add("IJulia")` to install the IJulia package.
Stacktrace:
 [1] macro expansion
   @ ./loading.jl:1163 [inlined]
 [2] macro expansion
   @ ./lock.jl:223 [inlined]
 [3] require(into::Module, mod::Symbol)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:1144
in expression starting at /home/user/anaconda3/envs/julialang/share/julia/packages/IJulia/AQu2H/src/kernel.jl:1
[W 22:40:44.021 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restart failed
[W 22:40:44.022 NotebookApp] Kernel c0c716fc-b629-46d7-aa29-44e1cb91c0fc died, removing from map.
[W 22:40:46.522 NotebookApp] Forbidden
[W 22:40:46.522 NotebookApp] 403 GET /api/contents/Untitled3.ipynb?content=0&_=1666456825272 (127.0.0.1) 1.370000ms referer=http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Untitled3.ipynb?kernel_name=julia-1.8
[W 22:40:48.314 NotebookApp] Forbidden
[W 22:40:48.314 NotebookApp] 403 GET /api/sessions?_=1666456701944 (127.0.0.1) 0.990000ms referer=http://localhost:8888/tree
[W 22:40:48.316 NotebookApp] Forbidden
[W 22:40:48.316 NotebookApp] 403 GET /api/terminals?_=1666456701945 (127.0.0.1) 1.200000ms referer=http://localhost:8888/tree
[W 22:40:49.820 NotebookApp] 403 POST /api/shutdown (127.0.0.1) 11.230000ms referer=http://localhost:8888/tree
^C[I 22:41:09.376 NotebookApp] interrupted
Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/user
0 active kernels
Jupyter Notebook 6.4.12 is running at:
http://localhost:8888/?token=e67639f228570093a6050632d9de6e98870f034e2923bfb5
 or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=e67639f228570093a6050632d9de6e98870f034e2923bfb5
Shutdown this notebook server (y/[n])? ^C[C 22:41:09.614 NotebookApp] received signal 2, stopping
[I 22:41:09.615 NotebookApp] Shutting down 0 kernels
[I 22:41:09.616 NotebookApp] Shutting down 1 terminal
[I 22:41:09.635 NotebookApp] EOF on FD 14; stopping reading
[I 22:41:09.736 NotebookApp] Terminal 1 closed
```

The following is the output from Julia console when running the Pkg.status() command:

```
julia> versioninfo(); using Pkg; Pkg.status()
Julia Version 1.8.2
Platform Info:
  OS: Linux (x86_64-conda-linux-gnu)
  CPU: 4 × Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7200U CPU @ 2.50GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-13.0.1 (ORCJIT, skylake)
  Threads: 1 on 4 virtual cores
Environment:
  JULIA_CONDAPKG_BACKEND_BACKUP = 
  JULIA_CONDAPKG_BACKEND = System
  JULIA_LOAD_PATH = @:@julia:@stdlib
  JULIA_LOAD_PATH_BACKUP = 
  JULIA_DEPOT_PATH_BACKUP = 
  JULIA_PROJECT_BACKUP = 
  JULIA_CONDAPKG_EXE = /home/user/anaconda3/bin/conda
  JULIA_SSL_CA_ROOTS_PATH = /home/user/anaconda3/envs/julia/ssl/cacert.pem
  JULIA_DEPOT_PATH = /home/user/anaconda3/envs/julia/share/julia:
  JULIA_PROJECT = @julia
  JULIA_SSL_CA_ROOTS_PATH_BACKUP = 
  JULIA_CONDAPKG_EXE_BACKUP = 
Status `~/anaconda3/envs/julia/share/julia/environments/julia/Project.toml`
  [7073ff75] IJulia v1.23.3
```

Could someone please help resolve the issue?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Anaconda environments, but it seems like you have two different ones here: Jupyter is trying to use the one in `/home/user/anaconda3/envs/julialang/`, while your REPL is using `/home/user/anaconda3/envs/julia/`.

Comment: exactly as Sundar said. The best option is to install Anaconda from Julia (this works really well) rather then to install Julia from Anaconda (used to work poorly, I have not tested with 1.8 though)

Comment: @Sundar R Thank you for pointing out the discrepancy. Actually, I followed the instruction from  here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-julia-in-an-anaconda-environment/
In linux mint, however, I ran into a precompile error for IJulia package which I am still not sure how to solve. 
I think the resolution to my current problem is similar to here: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/install-julia-with-anaconda-on-windows10/19571
But I cannot translate this to Anaconda on Linux Mint. No similar "Scripts" folder or "Jupyter.exe" file, in linux distribution.

Comment: @Przemyslaw Szufel Thanks for the input. I will create a separate directory for Julia outside of Anaconda environment and try to integrate conda with Julia following the instructions here: https://github.com/JuliaPy/Conda.jl
My goal is to run the julia kernel on jupyter notebook. Actually, I wanted to have everything in one place and use Julia as another separate environment in Anaconda.

Comment: @Przemyslaw Szufel It worked. I setup Julia outside anaconda in a separate directory. Then, installed the Conda package using Julia REPL. After installation, running the import Conda command on Julia console followed by Conda.list() automatically linked all the preinstalled Anaconda/conda packages with Julia. Finally, added the IJulia package using the julia REPL and now there is no ERROR when running the Julia 1.8.2 kernel via Jupyter Notebook.

Answer (score 0):

Since comments worked for Ayan here is the answer:

1. You should preferably install Anaconda from Julia (this works really well) rather then to install Julia from Anaconda.
2. Hence make a separate Julia installation and just run from Julia:

```
using Pkg
pkg"add PyCall Conda IJulia"
using Conda
Conda.add("jupyter")
```

Now you should be able to run notebook via `IJulia.notebook()` and in most cases this installation will be also visible to other Anacondas on your system.